# When talking about time durations can we use "at" and "to"?

Tags: prepositions, time

When talking about **time durations**, can we use **at** ... **to**? For example:

> The class is **at** 5pm **to** 6pm.

I know the ideal use would be:

> The class is **from** 5pm **to** 6pm.

Comment: `The one hour [long] class is at 5pm`?

Comment: No, at...to really sounds queer, though one can understand what you mean.

Comment: The class *begins at five and goes to (lasts until) six* would work. **Is at** indicates a momentary point in time.

Comment: You *can*, in much the same way that you *can* drop-kick a brick.  (In other words, you shouldn't.)

Comment: Sorry, Lydia, and the *ideal* use would be not *is* but 'The class *lasts* or *runs* from 5pm to 6pm.'

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that ***at*** only works for *one specific referent* (literally, a single location in space; metaphorically, one moment in time). It's not suitable for a *range* of locations / times.

As OP recognises, ***from*** [StartTime] **to** [EndTime] is a valid usage. I wouldn't say it's "ideal" though - it's just one alternative to consider when making what's essentially a stylistic choice.

In *many* contexts (including OP's exact example), ***between*** [StartTime] **and** [EndTime] could be a good choice. But that won't always work, because sometimes it might be understood to mean that the *[class, whatever] **starts at some point within** that time span* (and finishes at an unspecified time which might be within or beyond that range). But it's also fine to dispense with the first preposition entirely...

> *The class is 5pm to 6pm.*

Answer (score 0):

I would probably say that the class starts at 5pm and finishes at 6pm

Comment: or: *...starts at 5pm and runs until 6pm.*

Comment: or '... at 5pm, lasting to/till 6pm.'